# Java 8 - Call interface's default method with double colon syntax

Tags: java, inheritance, lambda, java-8

I'm delving into the Java 8 innovations, and I'm trying to call a default method which I implement in a high-level interface, even when a subclass overrides it. I would have no problem going back to implementing a `Comparator` in my `BusinessLogic` class, but I was wondering if there's some magic that lets me use the nifty new `::`.

Code:

```
public interface IdEntity extends Comparable<IdEntity> {

    int getId();

    @Override
    default int compareTo(IdEntity other) {
        return getId() - other.getId();
    }
}

public class Game implements IdEntity {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(IdEntity o) {
        if (o instanceof Game) {
            Game other = (Game) o;
            int something;
            // logic
            return something;
        }
        return super.compareTo(o);
    }
}

public class BusinessLogic {
    private void sortList(List<? extends IdEntity> list) {
        // for Game, Game::compareTo gets called but I want, in this call only, the default method
        Collections.sort(list, IdEntity::compareTo);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean with implementing a `Comparator` ? As I stated, there's nothing wrong, but this looked like an ideal situation to use `::`, until I discovered that the lambda goes to the runtime type. So I wondered if I could use the much improved syntax anyway.

Comment: it does indeed - I didn't expect that.

Comment: I don't believe this is even possible with `IdEntity` and `Game` written as stated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to put the compare method in a static method:

```
public static interface IdEntity extends Comparable<IdEntity> {
  int getId();
  @Override default int compareTo(IdEntity other) {
    return defaultCompare(this, other);
  }
  static int defaultCompare(IdEntity first, IdEntity second) {
    return first.getId() - second.getId();
  }
}
```

Then your method would be:

```
Collections.sort(list, IdEntity::defaultCompare);
```

Comment: Beautiful, this did the trick. I hadn't thought of a static method in my interface, because it's also new in Java 8

Comment: I would also consider `Collections.sort(list, comparingInt(IdEntity::getId))`, statically importing `java.util.Comparator.comparingInt`.  This makes it pretty clear up front what the comparison is actually doing and is nearly as compact.

Comment: That is actually even better, @LouisWasserman, because then I don't have to change the `IdEntity` interface. If you post that as an answer, I'll most definitely upvote.

Answer (score 5):

Simpler approach: static import `Comparator.comparingInt` and use

```
Collections.sort(list, comparingInt(IdEntity::getId));
```

I don't believe you can re-extract the default `compareTo` implementation: it's been overridden; you usually can't run an overridden method implementation.  But this will just work straightforwardly.

Answer (score 2):

Some general notes:

If a class overrides a superclass method, there is no way for *other* classes to deliberately invoke the superclass method, i.e. ignore the fact that this method has been overridden. Forbidding such bypassing is a fundamental design decision of the Java programming language.

The only class which may explicitly invoke the overridden method is the class which does the override and, of course, only on an instance of itself. Thus, within `Game.compareTo` you may invoke the overridden `IdEntity.compareTo` using `IdEntity.super.compareTo` which will invoke the method on the `this` instance.

You may also create a method reference to this `super` invocation but as it’s only allowed on the `this` instance, the `this` instance must be bound and can’t be a parameter of the functional signature. E.g. within an instance method of `Game` you can write:

```
ToIntFunction<IdEntity> f=IdEntity.super::compareTo;
```

This function will invoke the `default` method `IdEntity.compareTo` on the current `Game` instance, passing through the `IdEntity` argument.

---

But the entire design should be questioned. You should never create a class hierarchy in which non-`abstract` `compareTo` methods fulfilling the `Comparable` contract are overridden. This is an anti-pattern which will lead to bugs and surprising behavior. As [Louis Wasserman has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30766428/2711488), there is an easy way for creating a `Comparator` for the desired behavior. If the natural order for `Game` instances differs from the general `IdEntity` order, at least one of them isn’t a “natural order” and therefore should be expressed as `Comparator` only, maybe even both.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public interface IdEntity /* not Comparable<IdEntity> */ {
    int getId();
    static Comparator<IdEntity> defaultOrder() {
        return Comparator.comparingInt(IdEntity::getId);
    }
}
```

If you consider `Game` having a *natural order*:

```
public class Game implements IdEntity,Comparable<Game> {

    public int compareTo(Game o) {
        int something;
        // logic
        return something;
    }
    // …
}
```

or if the default `Game` order is just an alternative to the `IdEntity.defaultOrder()`:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Game implements IdEntity {

    public static Comparator<Game> defaultGameOrder() {
        return (a,b) -> {
            int something;
            // logic
            return something;
        };
    }
    // …
}
```